# How to pass value from ejs form to nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

The below code works fine, while fetching.. but i don't want the subflag div occupying the space which affects the submit button in displaying in correct position. Is there any other way possible to pass the values to app.js

```js
app.post("/activitieslist/:id/edit", function(req. res) {
  var astname = req.body.astname;
  var subflag = req.body.subflag;
  console.log(astname, subflag);
  });
```

```html
<form action="/activitieslist/<%= activitylist._id %>/edit" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Asset Name :
        </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="astname" value="<%= activitylist.astname %>">
</div>
<div class="form-group invisible">
      <input type="text" name="subflag" value="N">
</div>
<button class ="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use form post method or jquery or ajax

Comment: I have used post method in the example code above @RatanUdayKumar